# Are environmental variables language specific?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, group-policy

I need to setup a script in group policy that we be used in different regions of the world. Are environmental variables such as %ProgramFiles% language specific? I'm hoping that a script of %ProgramFiles% can be used both in spain and france even though their language is setup for the specific regions.

Thanks

Comment: If you're talking about different human languages and such, you might want to phrase it as something like "locale specific".  There's a difference between something that works differently in C++ and Java versus something that works differently in English and French, and "language" around here will be interpreted as "computer language" at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. They are not language specific.

When you use %ProgramFiles% the operating system will check in Windows registry where %ProgramFiles% maps to. This mapping is done during Windows installation and therefore using the placeholder %ProgramFiles% you'll have a language/country agnostic solution.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

No, but do watch out. I encountered a application that looked in "c:\Program Files" (hard coded, apparently). Tried to run it on a German (maybe it was French? Don't recall) version of Windows. "Program Files" is something else in German - I don't recall what, but it didn't parse as expected and of course the program failed.